# t-sql conditional date processing

Tags: t-sql, datetime

I have a stored procedure which returns data used in a report.  There are numerous paramters the user can specify, two of which are a start and end date. I can use a `WHERE create_date BETWEEN @arg_start AND @arg_end` statement to filter on the dates.

What I dont know how to do is to handle the situation where the user doesnt supply any dates.  `CASE` doesnt support anything like `WHERE create_date = CASE @arg_start WHEN NULL THEN create_date ELSE BETWEEN @arg_start AND @arg_end`.

I've done a lot of research on google, msdn, and here and I haven't find out to handle conditional null datetime processing.  Although I know its bad form, I can pass programatically pass in a magic date, such as 1/1/1900, to test instead of a null, but that doesn't really help in conditional date processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the default values for the stored procedure parameters the "magic dates":

```
CREATE PROC usp_report 
    @StartDate datetime = '1900-01-01', 
    @EndDate datetime = '9999-12-31' 

AS

SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE DateField BETWEEN @Startdate AND @EndDate
```

In your application, if the user has not specified a date, don't pass that parameter to the stored proc.

This would keep your application code clean, and give you the data you need.

Answer (score 3):

Make it a multi-part condition:

```
WHERE
    (@argstart IS NULL AND @argend IS NULL)
OR  (@argend IS NULL AND create_date > @Argstart)
OR  (@argstart IS NULL AND create_date < @argend)
OR  (Createdate BETWEEN @Argstart AND @Argend)
```

Comment: +1  This is the best answer I think; while Mikael's answer is more elegant, [there's actually a benefit to structuring the `WHERE` clause like this](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html#AND_ISNOTNULL).

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
where (create_date >= @arg_start or @arg_start is null) and
      (create_date <= @arg_end or @arg_end is null)
```

If you are on SQL Server 2008 you should use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`. Ref: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL
Version for SQL 2008 (SP1 CU5 and later)](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html).

Otherwise you might be better of using the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8824847/569436) provided by [JNK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk).

Comment: +1 - More elegant than my solution but I think you get the same results.

Comment: @JNK - A bit of "reading" shows that both our answer might be the best depending on SQL Server version. Apparently `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is available in SQL Server 2005 but does not work in this case.

Comment: Well they both give the right answer which is the important part, I think.

Comment: [Shawn's answer is perfectly legit as well](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html#Umachandar). `BETWEEN` can use a range seek.